# How to configure dispatcher correctly in asp.net core akka

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka-dispatcher

I am adding a pinned dispatcher to my akka.net configuration as I read this will give a timely manner to my dispatch messages to my actor but as I followed akka configuration I came up with this

```
 using (_actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("SchedulerAutoAction"))
            {
                var props = Props.Create<TaskSchedulerAktor>().WithDispatcher("pinned-dispatcher"); // handle the mailbox timely
                _actorRef = _actorSystem.ActorOf(props, "TaskSchedulerAutoActionActor");
            }
```

as I want to run this based on pinned dispatcher but currently I got this error in my terminal

```
Unhandled Exception: Akka.Configuration.ConfigurationException: Dispatcher [pinned-dispatcher] not configured for path akka://SchedulerAutoAction/user/TaskSchedulerAutoActionActor
   at Akka.Actor.LocalActorRefProvider.ActorOf(ActorSystemImpl system, Props props, IInternalActorRef supervisor, ActorPath path, Boolean systemService, Deploy deploy, Boolean lookupDeploy, Boolean async)
```

does anyone use dispatcher and configure it correctly? Can you suggest any improvement to my code? Please let me know

Answer (score -1):

The string argument that you're passing as dispatcher's identifier, is in fact a HOCON path in your actor system configuration: for [PinnedDispatcher](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/dispatchers.html#pinneddispatcher) the path could be i.e. [akka.io.pinned-dispatcher](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/d3b56f081dd13eae8c3bbf7b8624f77d3b115851/src/core/Akka/Configuration/Pigeon.conf#L521).

PS: Keep in mind, that you can create your own pinned settings - details are in the documentation I've linked above.